# Need help with ajax

Tags: ajax

I have been using using PHP and pure Javascript for wordpress for a while, but I never manage to use AJAX.
Currently I am trying to make an ajax call from one of my wordpress page by putting AJAX JS code directly into the page trying to call a PHP function from a file ajax.php (same dir with functions.php)

I have gone through many tutorial online regarding this part but no success. Even calling a simple PHP function just to echo "Hello World" doesn't work for me.
I am positive that I don't need any "enqueue" for this part (since I am putting JS code in the page directly).

If someone can shed me some light on how can one make a very simple AJAX call using Javascript to activate a PHP function from the server (a very simple example would be really helpful), I would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Comment: You are doing it very wrong. no idea what did you read, but nothing that you have done is actually right :( read the official tutorials and follow them.

Comment: When I try to put the sample codes into my page and run it. It even break the whole page. That's why I am having this much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The [WordPress Plugin Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) has background info and code samples of how to use Ajax in your plugin (and themes). Give it a read and it should get you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple AJAX call on button click.

Note the standard **wp_ajax_{action_name}** only fires for logged-in users. If you need to also listen for Ajax requests that don't come from logged-in users, you need to use **wp_ajax_nopriv_{action_name}**

## JS:

```
$('body').on('click', '.your-button', function(){
    var data = {
        'action': 'nam_nguyen_hook',
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert( response.message );
    }, 'json');
});
```

## PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nam_nguyen_hook', 'nam_nguyen_hook' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_nam_nguyen_hook', 'nam_nguyen_hook' );

function nam_nguyen_hook() {
    $response = array();

    $response['status']  = 200;
    $response['message'] = 'Successfully sent an AJAX request';

    echo json_encode( $response );
    wp_die();
}
```

With this, if you have an element with `class="your-button"` in your admin, and click on it - you should get the "Successfully sent an AJAX request" message back.

Also note you need to make sure your `ajax.php` file is being required or included. Otherwise just put that PHP in your `functions.php` file.

Comment: So I went on a head and try this
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("#export").click(function() {
    alert("clicked!");
    var data = {
        'action': 'export_excel'
    };

    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert( response.message );
    }, 'json');
  });
});
</script>
<button id="export" class="button">Export All to Excel</button>

while in functions.php, I just put the same thing with what you have for PHP, except changing 'nam_nguyen_hook' into 'export_excel', but I couldn't get anything back...